# How to read from user and put it in address bar?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a web application in PHP. I need a task to be done that is I want to take an input from a user in a search form and the term user have given must be added to address for a specific task.

For example: User is given an input such as obama now I want it should be added to address bar URL such as **www.somedomain.com/something/obama**.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Test Page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>

   <form class="form-wrapper" method="POST" 
   action="http://www.somedomainname.com/">
   <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for..." required >
   <input  class="form-control" type="submit" value="go" id="submit">
   </form>

   </body> 
</html>
```

Now I want that what user give as input then it must redirect to www.somedomainname.com/searchterm.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: so far just created a form in HTML.

Comment: Update your post with relevant code

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish by putting it in the url.  Aesthetics for the user?  Redirect? Bookmarking?

Comment: Redirect after adding the term user input

Comment: After click of Go button you need to redirect to specific url with user entered data is it ? Example http://vitaltesting.spacedragoon.com/Obama  ??

Comment: Yes I need this

Comment: Before you get fancy with redirects, have you even successfully submitted the form and processed the input?

Comment: use `<form method='get'`  (not post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Your input for search does not have a name. So the post will not work.

2)Your form action call the php page handling the form.

3)Use `header()` to redirect

Try something like this.

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
   $name = htmlentities( $name, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding = 'UTF-8' );

   header('Location:http://somedomain.com'.$name);

 }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
 <div>
   <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </div>
 <div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: session is not needed if all they need is a redirect.  Your point #2 is not worded well. It doesn't have to be index.php, nor is action required (It will submit to the calling script).

Comment: have modified for the session part!

Answer (score 0):

Every input must contain a name tag if you use PHP to handle the form. Name tags are like human names and the users input defines what the human consists of.

If you want to handle your data on the same page as the user submits the form your action="" should be empty or contain `<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>`. The action of the form defines where your input data is sent. If you want to handle the form POST at fx senddata.php you want to write `action="senddata.php"`.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

---

To send data across pages you can use sessions or cookies. I wouldn't recommend using this just for a simple form. It is easier to send it with a form and use $_POST to get the data.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Keep on Coding!!